# Style is not working in inline style

Tags: php, html, css

Having a problem with following line.

```
echo "<p><font size=+1  style=\"font: 16px verdana,sans-serif; text-decoration:none; color: navy;\"> Use <b><a href=\"/showcal.php?ownerid=$ownerid\">mysite.com/showcal.php?ownerid=$ownerid </a></b> as link for your viewers.</font><br>";
```

Font: 16px is working. color:navy is working. text-decoration is not working.

Comment: don't test your app with IE (internet explorer)

Comment: text-decoration is affect on a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the text-decoration: none to the 'a' tag

```
echo "<p><font size=+1  style=\"font: 16px verdana,sans-serif; text-decoration:none; color: navy;\"> Use <b><a style=\"text-decoration:none;\" href=\"/showcal.php?ownerid=$ownerid\">mysite.com/showcal.php?ownerid=$ownerid </a></b> as link for your viewers.</font><br>";
```

Answer (score 2):

`text-decoration` is already `none` on the ([deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font)) `font` element. That's the default.

And it's not an inheritable property, so the `a` can't get it from the parent.

Apply the `text-decoration: none` to the `a` element.